# Python while loop with string

Tags: python, string, loops, while-loop

```
string = "Northeastern Africa"
myString = string.lower()
index = 0
num_index = int(index)

length = len(myString)
num_length = int(length)
num_length = num_length - 1

while myString[num_index] >=  myString[18]:
    print(num_index)
    print(num_length)
    print(myString[num_index])
    print(num_index)
    num_index = num_index +1
    print(myString[0:num_index])
    print(" ")
```

why does it only print "northeastern" and stops at the next space?  how do i make it go through the full string without stopping at the space in between both words?

Comment: What is `myString` here?

Comment: `index` and `length` are already integers. There is no need to convert them to integers again.

Comment: Your code won't work the way you state if your string really starts with a capital `N`. Are you sure it doesn't start with a `n` (lowercase)?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Have you figured out what he's trying to do in the first place?

Comment: oh sorry, myString = string.lower()

Comment: so when i run it, it works but it stops at the space between both words and doesn't run until its done with both words, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop compares each character with the last, `a`, stopping when it finds a character that isn't equal or higher than `a`. Your code stops at the space because the latter's position in the ASCII table is 32:

```
>>> ' ' < 'a'
True
>>> ord(' ')
32
>>> ord('a')
97
```

You probably wanted to create a loop comparing `num_index` to `num_length` instead:

```
while num_index <= num_length:
```

If you wanted to loop through all characters in a string, just use a `for` loop:

```
for character in myString:
    print(character)
```

You can use the `enumerate()` function to add an index:

```
for index, character in enumerate(myString):
    print(index, character, sep=': ')
    print(myString[:index])
```

Comment: ok, what im trying to do is to create a loop that counts the vowels in the string. that's why i wanted to go down the string letter by letter.

Comment: @user3294540: then just use the simple `for` loop and count your vowels! `if character in 'aeiou':`.

Answer (score 0):

because `myString[num_index]` value is space 
check this..

```
>>> " ">="a"
False
```